# Como colocar um numero inteiro em um label

Tags: java, conversão-de-tipo

Estou tentando colocar uma espécie de contador de pontuação em um Jlabel ex: você acerta uma questão a pontuação vai pra 1 , você erra e não acontece nada com a pontuação.

Tentei fazer isso dessa forma :

```
   private void confirmarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    while (true){
    String pont = " ";
    int pontuacao = Integer.parseInt(pont);
    if (confirmar == a){
        a.setBackground(Color.green);

    }else{
         a.setBackground(Color.red);
    }

   }

}
```

Erro:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " "

Comment: O erro é porque você está tentando converter string vazia para inteiro.

Comment: Obrigado novamente por me ajudar diego :D , bom eu acabei solucionando meu problema ( coisa muito fácil ) , eu só criei um int pontuacao = 0; 
tirei o while e coloquei pont.setText(" "+pontuacao);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Está a dar erro porque tu estás a declarar `pont` como `String` e estás a tentar converter `" "` para `Int` e como é óbvio vai dar erro de conversão. É **impossivel** convertares **nada para inteiro**, inteiro  tem que ter sempre algum valor númerico.

Comment: `inteiro tem que ter sempre algum valor.` isso não é exatamente verdade. Nem todo valor pode ser convertido para inteiro.

Comment: Tens razão algum valor **númerico**, já corrigi ;)